# Query to find Cumulative while subtracting other counts

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is my table structure

```
Id     INT
RecId  INT
Dated  DATETIME
Status INT
```

and here is my data.

Status table (contains different statuses)

```
Id   Status
1    Created
2    Assigned
```

Log table (contains logs for the different statuses that a record went through (RecId))

```
Id   RecId     Dated                              Status  

1     1       2013-12-09 14:16:31.930               1
2     7       2013-12-09 14:27:26.620               1
3     1       2013-12-09 14:27:26.620               2
3     8       2013-12-10 11:14:13.747               1
3     9       2013-12-10 11:14:13.747               1
3     8       2013-12-10 11:14:13.747               2
```

What I need to generate a report from this data in the following format.

```
Dated                     Created                   Assigned
2013-12-09                 2                         1
2013-12-10                 3                         1
```

Here the rows data is calculated date wise. The Created is calculated as (previous record (date) Created count - Previous date Assigned count) + Todays Created count.

For example if on date 2013-12-10 three entries were made to log table out of which two have the status Created while one has the status assigned. So in the desired view that I want to build for report, For date   2013-12-10, the view will return Created as 2 + 1 = 3 where 2 is newly inserted records in log table and 1 is the previous day remaining record count (Created - Assigned) 2 - 1.

I hope the scenario is clear. Please ask me if further information is required.

Please help me with the sql to construct the above view.

Comment: Is it true to assume that the seqance of records is "created and then assigned?" So the records date will be smaller for created than assigned?

Comment: @Mike exactly Created comes before for a record than assigned

Answer (score 1):

This matches the expected result for the provided sample, but may require more testing.

```
with CTE as (
        select
                  *
                , row_number() over(order by dt ASC) as rn
        from (
              select
                      cast(created.dated as date) as dt
                    , count(created.status)       as Created
                    , count(Assigned.status)      as Assigned
                    , count(created.status) 
                      - count(Assigned.status)    as Delta
              from LogTable created
              left join LogTable assigned
                           on created.RecId = assigned.RecId
                          and created.status = 1
                          and assigned.Status = 2
                          and created.Dated <= assigned.Dated
              where created.status = 1
              group by
                      cast(created.dated as date)
          ) x
     )
select
    dt.dt
  , dt.created + coalesce(nxt.delta,0) as created
  , dt.assigned
from CTE dt
left join CTE nxt on dt.rn = nxt.rn+1
;
```

Result:

```
|         DT | CREATED | ASSIGNED |
|------------|---------|----------|
| 2013-12-09 |       2 |        1 |
| 2013-12-10 |       3 |        1 |
```

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9908c/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but this will only return the count of created without considering how many of them were assigned. Say for example yesterday 5 were created out of which 2 were assigned. And today 3 were created so today's created count will be (5-2)+3 = 6

Comment: what version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Answer revised. Note this would be simpler using sql server 2012 through lead and lag functions.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, dt.dt = dateadd(day,1,nxt.dt) give 0 for 'Previous date Assigned count' on gaps in date's sequence. Is it right or not?  I would join CTE's on order-by-date rownum in CTE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c6e1/23

Comment: give 0 for 'Previous date Assigned count' on gaps in date's sequence:: yes it would. The problem is if you use less than or some device like that you need up with more joins than you want or need. It is possible to use row_number() to get around this, but I don't have time to do this right now.

Comment: I have altered this solution to use a join based on row_number() this will allow dates to be non-contiguous